# Copy array by values and not by reference with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm searching for a solution to copy an array from another one so I can manipulate my second array. But the problem is when I make a change in the second, it also affects the first.

Example :

```
var array1 = [1 , 2 , 3];
var array2 = array1;

array2.splice(0,2);
```

Result :

```
array2 : [3];
array1 : [3];
```

But what I expect :

```
array1 : [1 , 2 , 3];
array2 : [3];
```

Any solution for this ?

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code

```
var array1 = [1 , 2 , 3];
var array2 = array1.slice();

array2.splice(0,2);
```

Comment: It's typically more desirable to use `.slice()` instead of `.splice()` when "copying" to avoid modifying the original array in the process.